# Problema con python-nmap

Tags: python, nmap

Instalé la librería `python-nmap` cuando ejecuto el código:

```
nm = nmap.PortScanner()
```

Me sale error como se muestra en la imagen, sé que tiene que ver con el path, no se configurarlo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El error dice que no encuentra el programa `nmap`. Tienes que configurarlo y agregarlo a tu ruta. ¿Lo tienes instalado? ¿Puedes ejecutar `nmap` en tu computadora? Si no puedes, ese es el problema y pues esta pregunta no tiene mucha razón de ser. Verifícalo, por favor.

Comment: Si ya lo tienes instalado, debes asignarlo a la variable de entorno `PATH` de tu windows.